# Function that uses all arguments in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use all arguments from my function like this

```
function docker_run {
  docker run \
    -it --rm \
    --entrypoint "" \
    --volume "$(pwd):/${repo}" \
    --workdir "/${repo}" \
    alpine/git:v2.26.2 \
    "$*"
}

docker_run sh -c "git reset && git add --a && git status"
```

this gives the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: "sh -c git reset && git add --a && git status": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

if I remove quotes around `$*` the error is:

> usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C ]...

is `*$` the correct variable to use? ideally I'd want `docker_run` to work with any possible argument combination

Comment: `"$*"` concatenates the separate arguments into a single space-separated string. Use `"$@"` to preserve the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use all arguments, you should use `$@` and not `$*`. `$@` is special in that it's array-like, so when you put it in quotes it expands to all arguments. `$*` is a string that joins the arguments with spaces, so it globs into one argument.